LmCompatibilityLevel gets set back to 4
I want to apply LmCompatibilityLevel 5 to a Windows Server 2016 machine but the next day it always gets set back to 4.
I've already both modified the registry by hand and applied a GPO to set it to 5.
How can I know what is causing this or how could I permanently set it to 5?

Is it possible there is another GPO trumping this setting?
